# Set id for None object

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have model for my comments:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    body = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="comment")
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments", verbose_name="message")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="author")
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', verbose_name='parent', default=None)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="posted")
    edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="edited")

def __str__(self):
    return self.body

def get_create_url(self):
    return reverse('wall:add-comment', kwargs={'id': self.message.id, 'pk': self.parent.id})

def get_update_url(self):
    return reverse('wall:edit-comment', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

I need to get an id for parent.id if parent is none.

Comment: `self.parent.id if self.parent else "myId"` ?

Comment: It worked. Thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't access the `parent_id` if there is no `parent`. (You can't drive *your own car* if you don't have one)
If you want to return some data if `parent` is `None`, try this

```
comment = Comment.objects.get(id=instance_id)
if not comment.parent:
    return comment.id
return comment.parent_id
```

This will return `parent_id` if it has  a `parent` else it will return it's own `id`

Comment: Thanks, I already figured out there, good advice, will help in the future